# Call inner method onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For an onClick event I need to call a method which is nested inside another method. The React code is based on React Hooks.

### App.js

```
import ..........
bla bla bla

const App = () => {
  const a = () => {
    const b = () => {
      console.log("Testing")
    }
  }
  return (
    <Button onClick={()=>b()}>
      Click Me
    </Button>
  )
}
```

For this above example I need to call b() onClick. Because in my real App b() method depends on something from a() method. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this :

```
const a = () => {
    // do your regular stuff
    return () => {
      console.log("Testing")
    }
}

<button onClick={()=>a()()}>
```

You can review by "Run the code snippet"

```js
const App = () => {
  const a = () => {
    return () => {
      console.log("Testing")
    }
  }
  
  const a2 = () => {
    const b = () => {
      console.log("Testing from @giorgim")
    }
    return {b}
  };

  return (
    <div>
    <button onClick={()=>a()()}>
      Click Me
    </button>
    <br/><br/>
    <button onClick={()=>a2().b()}>
      Click Me Via @giorgim
    </button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by setState what I want in b() method. And reuse it from b() separately. Thank you all for the support